# How to disable or lock To/Subject fielf of new mail window using outlook addin 2010

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin

I am able to read the current mail item of the active inspector, i am able to assign values to those fields programmatically. But what i need to do id disable or lock the fields from user input.

If anyone have an idea about it, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how jquery or MVC are applicable to this?

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of finding the right HWND and disabling it using `EnableWWindow` Windows API function.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a way of preventing the user from editing that field directly - you may be able to if you are using form regions and can override the subject field directly (by perhaps using a replace form region rather than an adjoining).

The best I think you can do is to store the immutable value for the subject on startup, bind to the event that fires when the user changes that field, and revert it back to the immutable value.

The PropertyChange property of the MailItem object https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866739 is what you need to listen for.

Example:

```
// within your startup method
this._MailItem.PropertyChange += MailItem_PropertyChange;
this.mySubject = "Don't change me!";

function MailItem_PropertyChange(string Name)
{
    if (Name.Equals("Subject")) // or whatever
    {
        // do something here like this.Subject = this.mySubject;
        // and maybe alert the user the field can't be changed
    }
}
```

Comment: The event is not fired until you try to save the item or switch to another field in the inspector window. This is a well-known issue.

Comment: Thanks John, but I want to disable certain field when new mail window is opened.